# How does strdup() in K&R chapter 6 work when it doesn't assign sizeof(char) * strlen(s) bits?

Tags: c, malloc

In K&R Chapter 6 they have the function `strdup(char *s)` which is meant to copy `s` into memory and return its location, `p`.

```
/* strdup: make a duplicate of s */ 
char *strdup(char *s) {
    char *p; 

    p = (char *)malloc(strlen(s) + 1); /* plus one for '\0' */ 
    if (p != NULL) 
        strcpy(p, s); 
    return p; 
}
```

However, in the `malloc` call, they only assign `strlen(s) + 1` bytes. In order for this array of chars to work, wouldn't it have to be: `malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(s) + 1))`?

Answer (score 7):

`sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`, so

```
malloc( sizeof(char) * ( strlen(s) + 1 ) )
```

simplifies to

```
malloc( strlen(s) + 1 )
```

Note:

- `sizeof` returns a size in bytes (not bits).
- `malloc` requires a size in bytes (not bits).
- A byte (`char`) may have more than 8 bits. (The amount is given by `CHAR_BIT`.)